# replace values in R

Tags: r, replace, factors

in my large dataset, I have a column named car density (factors), they are like

```
"001: 0-3.8998943958"
"061:2290.611052-2391.7437"
```

I want to replace these with the median of each range. there are nearly 10000 observations.
I tried the long way:
`"1.9499"<-sb$CAR_Density[sb$CAR_Density == "001: 0-3.8998943958"]`, which did not work. I should not put "" on 1.9499, because I want the outcome values to be numeric.

Is there a efficient and understandable way to do this?
I am not so good at programming, please help.

Comment: What, according to you, should the code `"1.9499"<-sb$CAR_Density[sb$CAR_Density == "001: 0-3.8998943958"]` do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have it the wrong way around, you want

```
sb$CAR_Density[sb$CAR_Density == "001: 0-3.8998943958"] <- 1.9499
```

If you tell us a bit more about your data, we can show an automated way of replacing each unique value with a median - but i am lost as to how the densities convert into medians given your example.

Comment: it is a dataset with 20 variables and 10000 observations. one of the variable is named CAR_Density, there are 61 types of CAR_Density. each type of CAR_density is in this "001: 0-3.8998943958" format. where 001 is just a key, it goes up to 061. and 0-3.89989 is a range of density. I want to use the median number from 0 to 3.89989 instead of the whole"001: 0-3.8998943958". and I want to apply this to the other 60 CAR_Density types.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you define median but I think you're trying to achieve something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  a = c("001: 0-3.8998943958","061:2290.611052-2391.7437")
  )
df$a <- as.character(df$a)
for(i in 1:nrow(df))
{
df[i,"a1"] <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(strsplit(df$a,":")[[i]][2],"-")))[1]
df[i,"a2"] <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(strsplit(df$a,":")[[i]][2],"-")))[2]
}

df$amedian <- (df$a1 + df$a2)/2
```

Output

```
> df
                          a       a1          a2     amedian
1       001: 0-3.8998943958    0.000    3.899894    1.949947
2 061:2290.611052-2391.7437 2290.611 2391.743700 2341.177376
```

Comment: it is a dataset with 20 variables and 10000 observations. one of the variable is named CAR_Density, there are 61 types of CAR_Density. each type of CAR_density is in this "001: 0-3.8998943958" format. where 001 is just a key, it goes up to 061. and 0-3.89989 is a range of density. I want to use the median number from 0 to 3.89989 instead of the whole"001: 0-3.8998943958". and I want to apply this to the other 60 CAR_Density types.

Comment: `df$a` is the same column as your `CAR_density` then, right? The median number is `(0 + 3.89)/2`, yes? What do you mean by " I want to apply this to the other 60 CAR_Density types."? It will be easier if you post sample data and expected output.

Comment: "001: 0-3.8998943958", "002: 3.8998943958-7.224696", "003: 7.2246968432-12.37135", "004: 12.37135867-16.160174", "005: 16.160174419-20.74777".....these are original factor data, they will go up to "061: 2290.611052-2391.7437". I want to replace these these factors with numbers, replace "001: 0-3.8998943958" with 1.9499, replace "002: 3.8998943958-7.224696" with (7.224696+3.89989)/2, and so on. this column is named CAR_Density, data name is sb.  Eventually, I will do multiple regression, so I d like CAR_Density to be nice numeric data.

Comment: I think the solution I've posted answers your question in that case. The `df$amedian` column carries the 'median' values while your original factor column is `df$a`. Which part are you unclear on?

Comment: Thank you so much for you help. One more thing I have trouble with is how to replace the original column of data with the newly obtained median data. The trouble is that df$median has 61 medians, my original data has 10000 observations. In other words, many of the CAR_Density appeared more than once. How to replace the original 10000 observations with the new 61 medians?

Comment: `unique` will let you isolate the 61 values. You can put these 61 values in a new data.frame and operate on that.